# Responsive Design Issue: Elements Displace and Overlap When Zooming In/Out

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, zooming

I'm a beginner in web design, and I'm encountering a challenge with responsive design on my website. When I zoom in on my site, the elements within the container spread too far apart, leading to a disordered layout. Conversely, when I zoom out, these elements start overlapping and becoming too close to each other. Despite my use of relative units and media queries, the issue persists. I've tried solutions like the **`min-width`** property and **`transform: scale()`**, but none have fully resolved the problem.

**Problem Details:** I've included a screenshot of the problem I'm facing, where elements don't maintain their positions and alignment when zooming in or out. The layout disarray ruins the overall user experience. I've used relative units and media queries to ensure responsiveness, but these solutions haven't addressed the issue effectively. I'm looking for guidance on how to maintain a consistent layout while zooming in and out.

**Code:**

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>DEVELOPER PORTFOLIO STARTER</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Prata&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <div class="logo">Jhonathan Specter</div>
        <div class="options">
          <ul>
            <li>Articles</li>
            <li>Chats</li>
            <li>Awards</li>
            <li>About</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="getintouch">Get in touch</div>
      </nav>
      <main>
        <div class="section1">
          <div class="sec1dis">
            Helping companies build<br />better, scalable software.
          </div>
          <div class="sec1para">
            Award-winning web developer and author, with over 15+ years of
            working<br />experience with Fortune 500 companies like Apple,
            Google, Facebook, and<br />more.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="companieslogo">
          <img src="/Assets/Logos/Walmart.svg" />
          <img src="/Assets/Logos/JP Morgan.svg" />
          <img src="/Assets/Logos/Visa.svg" />
          <img src="/Assets/Logos/Tinder.svg" />
          <img src="/Assets/Logos/Samsung.svg" />
          <img src="/Assets/Logos/Verizon.svg" />
        </div>
        <div class="picturesec">
          <div class="spense">
            <div class="spenseimg">
              <img class="custom-image" src="/Assets/Spense.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="imgdis">Spense.com</div>
            <div class="imgpara">
              Rethinking the way writers get paid, an open-source platform
              designed to help writers focus more on writing, and less on when
              and how they'll get paid. Project in collaboration with
              Codewell.cc
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <div class="camp">
            <div class="campimg">
              <img src="/Assets/YelpCamp.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="imgdis">YelpCamp.com</div>
            <div class="imgpara">
              Allowing backpack travelers to perfectly plan their trip through
              an open-source platform similar to TripAdvisor. With over 1m MAU,
              YelpCamp has been the crowd's favorite in 2021.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
      <footer></footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav {
  height: 83px;
  width: 80%;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  font-family: "Prata", serif;
}

.options ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  gap: 25px;
  color: grey;
}

.getintouch {
  font-family: "Prata", serif;
  background-color: rgb(202, 202, 46);
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
}

main {
  height: 300px;
  width: 80%;
}

.section1 {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.sec1dis {
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  font-family: "Prata", serif;
}

.sec1para {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: grey;
}

.companieslogo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.companieslogo img {
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.picturesec {
  height: 475px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: white;
}

.spenseimg {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.spenseimg img {
  width: 506px;
  height: 280px;
}

.spacer {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.campimg {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.campimg img {
  width: 506px;
  height: 280px;
}

.imgdis {
  font-family: "Prata", serif;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.imgpara {
  color: grey;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

**Screenshot:** **[Current Layout Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3N08.png)**

**What I've Tried:**

- Adjusting margins, paddings, and widths using relative units.
- Implementing media queries to adapt to various screen sizes.
- Exploring **`transform: scale()`** to control zoom behavior.

**Desired Outcome:** I want my webpage's layout to remain intact even when users zoom in or out. The elements within the container should not displace, overlap, or compromise the visual appeal of the design. I've attached an example of the desired behavior in a **[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjcNs.png)**.